# Why does python freeze when I use configure_options to send a file to my nodes using add_file_option?

Tags: python, python-3.5, mrjob

I am trying to use the MRJob package in python. I want to send a file(u.item) along with my code to all the nodes, so I use the configure_options function and use the add_file_option to tell python that I am going to send you a file in my command line. When I run this command: 
!python MostPopularMovieNicer.py --items=u.item u.data
everything stops and python freezes without showing me anything.

I have already run the trace command and got this error:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.step import MRStep

class MostPopularMovieNicer(MRJob):

```
def configure_options(self):
    super(MostPopularMovieNicer, self).configure_options()
    self.add_file_option('--items', help='Path to u.item')

def steps(self):
    return [
        MRStep(mapper=self.mapper_get_ratings,
               reducer_init=self.reducer_init,
               reducer=self.reducer_count_ratings),
        MRStep(reducer = self.reducer_find_max)
    ]

def mapper_get_ratings(self, _, line):
    (userID, movieID, rating, timestamp) = line.split('\t')
    yield movieID, 1

def reducer_init(self):
    self.movieNames = {}

    with open("u.ITEM", encoding='ascii', errors='ignore') as f:
        for line in f:
            fields = line.split('|')
            self.movieNames[fields[0]] = fields[1]

def reducer_count_ratings(self, key, values):
    yield None, (sum(values), self.movieNames[key])


def reducer_find_max(self, key, values):
    yield max(values)
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    MostPopularMovieNicer.run()

No error is shown and python freezes. I have to exit the software to be able to run other codes.

Answer (score 0):

you should use **configure_args** and **add_file_arg** instead of configure_options and add_file_option.
configure_options is no longer useable in MRjob.
this link may help you : https://mrjob.readthedocs.io/en/latest/job.html